# Symfony2 - Add a most viewed post to the sidebar

Tags: symfony

I've noticed some websites that have a most viewed posts section. I am looking to add this functionality to the side bar.

How can you setup a method that determines how many posts have been selected by a user then add in the top 3 or so viewed posts?

For example here (towards the middle of the page in the sidebar, the most viewed): http://america.aljazeera.com/

Is there a bundle that incorporates this?

Or is there an easier method by using a count based on how many times a user clicks on a post?

Comment: Too broad. Have you tried something?

Comment: Want to get realistic data on visits or maybe is good a dirty method?
However, you do not have to perform a write to the database when your aim is to serve the page as quickly as possible.

Comment: @bartek I'm looking for the overall method on how to do this as I'm not sure how to setup how many times a user clicks on accesses an article. Can this be done solely in php or will Javascript be needed?

Comment: @Giuffre Realistic data on how posts have been accessed by the user to determine the most popular. Can you elaborate on the dirty method you're proposing?

Comment: you must save it to your entity if its clicked, then you can easy query for it

Comment: @john Smith can you provide an overall example of what you mean on how to set this up?

Comment: Update your `article`: add integer field `visited`. In your `ArticleController::showAction` update your entity after successful `find`. Example: `$article = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('yourRepo')->find($id); $article->incrementVisited();` Then just query the most visited article and render it on the `sidebar`

Comment: @bartek Can you elaborate on `$article->incrementVisted()`, is this a method I need to create or a built in function within Symfony2?

Comment: @bartek can you add your comments into a answer and i'll accept it. just still a little foggy on how to setup the +1 count for $article->incrementVisit();.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't know anyBundle doing that.

To have the 3 most viewed article you need to add a field in your database which save how much the article is important.

You have severals ways of doing it, this is what comes to my mind:
First: You add an relation ViewedByWeek -> Post.
Foreach post, this entity keep how much it have been visited.
Everytime an user visit the page, you improve the number of visits of the post for the current week.

Then, you can find the most popular post in the week, in the month, in the year.

If you don't use anything related to the time, the information will not be changing much